# VBA : vbYesNo displays a button with OK and nothing else

Tags: vba, extra

Title speaks for itself.

Here is an illustration

[image]

and here is the line of code I'm using.

```
If MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = Yes Then Exit Sub
```

I'm also using [**EXTRA! X-treme**](https://www.attachmate.com/library/docs/extra-x-treme.html)

Comment: `Const vbYesNo = 4` and `Const vbYes = 6`, what happen if you try `If MsgBox("Are you sure?", 4) = 6 Then Exit Sub`?

Comment: @R3uK Thank you that worked for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd have to guess that EXTRA! X-treme (wow! hyperbole much?!) is messing with the vb constants, or at least not respecting them if it is intercepting calls to the MsgBox function.

vbYesNo should be a constant numeric value of 4.

Also, instead of comparing the result of MsgBox to Yes, you should probably be comparing it to vbYes (numeric value of 6).

I think you're using VBA correctly (except for the vbYes part), so this might be an EXTRA! X-treme bug (or under-documented feature).

---

### Solution

```
If MsgBox("Are you sure?", 4) = 6 Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alan ! That worked fine, I edited your answer to add the corrected code. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
If DialogResult.OK = Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure ? ", "Choose Folder",System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Question) Then
  ' Do Code
End If
```